# How to run AWK script on tarce file to calculate Throughput of every single flow

Tags: loops, awk, throughput

I have trace file having data of multiple flows and an AWK script that calculates the throughput of a single flow.The script is given below.I want to run this script on trace file to collect throughput of flows from 1 to 200.As I know it requires a loop but

where should I place `for(loop_variable=1;loop_variable<=200;loop_variable++)`
to get output as flows againts their throughputs

Flow ID,        Average Throughput[kbps]

1              1783.69

2              1564.69

3        1233.69

4        1883.69

.

.

.

200     1523.45

```
# ==============================throughput.awk ========================
  BEGIN {
 recvdSize = 0
 startTime = 1e6
 stopTime = 0


}{
#for(loop_variable=1;loop_variable<=200;loop_variable++)<-- position this loop with proper scope
  # Trace line format: normal
  if ($2 != "-t") 
    {
    event = $1
    time = $2
    if (event == "+" || event == "-") node_id = $3
    if (event == "r" || event == "d") node_id = $4
    flow_id = $8
    pkt_id = $12
    pkt_size = $6
    flow_t = $5
    level = "AGT"
    }


    # Store start time
    if (level == "AGT" && (event == "+" || event == "s") && pkt_size >= 512 && time>= 120 && flow_id==loop_variable)
     {
      if (time < startTime) 
        {
          startTime = time
        }
    }
    # Update total received packets' size and store packets arrival time
    if (level == "AGT" && event == "r" && pkt_size >= 512 && time>=120 && flow_id==loop_variable) 
      {
      if (time > stopTime) 
        {
        stopTime = time
        }
        # Rip off the header
        hdr_size = pkt_size % 512
        pkt_size -= hdr_size
        # Store received packet's size
        recvdSize += pkt_size

      }

  }
  END {
 printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t",loop_variable,(recvdSize/(stopTime-startTime))*(8/1000))
}
```

Input file example.tr
[Trace File Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYo8w.gif)

```
r 1 1 101 tcp 40 ------- 2 1.0 104.0 0 1
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 2 1.0 104.0 0 1
r 1 2 101 tcp 40 ------- 3 2.0 105.0 0 2
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 3 2.0 105.0 0 2
r 1 3 101 tcp 40 ------- 4 3.0 106.0 0 3
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 4 3.0 106.0 0 3
r 1 4 101 tcp 40 ------- 5 4.0 107.0 0 4
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 5 4.0 107.0 0 4
r 1 5 101 tcp 40 ------- 6 5.0 108.0 0 5
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 6 5.0 108.0 0 5
r 1 6 101 tcp 40 ------- 7 6.0 109.0 0 6
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 7 6.0 109.0 0 6
r 1 7 101 tcp 40 ------- 8 7.0 110.0 0 7
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 8 7.0 110.0 0 7
r 1 8 101 tcp 40 ------- 9 8.0 111.0 0 8
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 9 8.0 111.0 0 8
r 1 9 101 tcp 40 ------- 10 9.0 112.0 0 9
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 10 9.0 112.0 0 9
r 1 10 101 tcp 40 ------- 11 10.0 113.0 0 10
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 11 10.0 113.0 0 10
r 1 11 101 tcp 40 ------- 12 11.0 114.0 0 11
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 12 11.0 114.0 0 11
r 1 12 101 tcp 40 ------- 13 12.0 115.0 0 12
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 13 12.0 115.0 0 12
r 1 13 101 tcp 40 ------- 14 13.0 116.0 0 13
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 14 13.0 116.0 0 13
r 1 14 101 tcp 40 ------- 15 14.0 117.0 0 14
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 15 14.0 117.0 0 14
r 1 15 101 tcp 40 ------- 16 15.0 118.0 0 15
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 16 15.0 118.0 0 15
r 1 16 101 tcp 40 ------- 17 16.0 119.0 0 16
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 17 16.0 119.0 0 16
r 1 17 101 tcp 40 ------- 18 17.0 120.0 0 17
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 18 17.0 120.0 0 17
r 1 18 101 tcp 40 ------- 19 18.0 121.0 0 18
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 19 18.0 121.0 0 18
r 1 19 101 tcp 40 ------- 20 19.0 122.0 0 19
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 20 19.0 122.0 0 19
r 1 20 101 tcp 40 ------- 21 20.0 123.0 0 20
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 21 20.0 123.0 0 20
r 1 21 101 tcp 40 ------- 22 21.0 124.0 0 21
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 22 21.0 124.0 0 21
r 1 22 101 tcp 40 ------- 23 22.0 125.0 0 22
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 23 22.0 125.0 0 22
r 1 23 101 tcp 40 ------- 24 23.0 126.0 0 23
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 24 23.0 126.0 0 23
r 1 24 101 tcp 40 ------- 25 24.0 127.0 0 24
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 25 24.0 127.0 0 24
r 1 25 101 tcp 40 ------- 26 25.0 128.0 0 25
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 26 25.0 128.0 0 25
r 1 26 101 tcp 40 ------- 27 26.0 129.0 0 26
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 27 26.0 129.0 0 26
r 1 27 101 tcp 40 ------- 28 27.0 130.0 0 27
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 28 27.0 130.0 0 27
r 1 28 101 tcp 40 ------- 29 28.0 131.0 0 28
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 29 28.0 131.0 0 28
r 1 29 101 tcp 40 ------- 30 29.0 132.0 0 29
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 30 29.0 132.0 0 29
r 1 30 101 tcp 40 ------- 31 30.0 133.0 0 30
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 31 30.0 133.0 0 30
r 1 31 101 tcp 40 ------- 32 31.0 134.0 0 31
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 32 31.0 134.0 0 31
r 1 32 101 tcp 40 ------- 33 32.0 135.0 0 32
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 33 32.0 135.0 0 32
r 1 33 101 tcp 40 ------- 34 33.0 136.0 0 33
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 34 33.0 136.0 0 33
r 1 34 101 tcp 40 ------- 35 34.0 137.0 0 34
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 35 34.0 137.0 0 34
r 1 35 101 tcp 40 ------- 36 35.0 138.0 0 35
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 36 35.0 138.0 0 35
r 1 36 101 tcp 40 ------- 37 36.0 139.0 0 36
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 37 36.0 139.0 0 36
r 1 37 101 tcp 40 ------- 38 37.0 140.0 0 37
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 38 37.0 140.0 0 37
r 1 38 101 tcp 40 ------- 39 38.0 141.0 0 38
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 39 38.0 141.0 0 38
r 1 39 101 tcp 40 ------- 40 39.0 142.0 0 39
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 40 39.0 142.0 0 39
r 1 40 101 tcp 40 ------- 41 40.0 143.0 0 40
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 41 40.0 143.0 0 40
r 1 41 101 tcp 40 ------- 42 41.0 144.0 0 41
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 42 41.0 144.0 0 41
r 1 42 101 tcp 40 ------- 43 42.0 145.0 0 42
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 43 42.0 145.0 0 42
r 1 43 101 tcp 40 ------- 44 43.0 146.0 0 43
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 44 43.0 146.0 0 43
r 1 44 101 tcp 40 ------- 45 44.0 147.0 0 44
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 45 44.0 147.0 0 44
r 1 45 101 tcp 40 ------- 46 45.0 148.0 0 45
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 46 45.0 148.0 0 45
r 1 46 101 tcp 40 ------- 47 46.0 149.0 0 46
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 47 46.0 149.0 0 46
r 1 47 101 tcp 40 ------- 48 47.0 150.0 0 47
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 48 47.0 150.0 0 47
r 1 48 101 tcp 40 ------- 49 48.0 151.0 0 48
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 49 48.0 151.0 0 48
r 1 49 101 tcp 40 ------- 50 49.0 152.0 0 49
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 50 49.0 152.0 0 49
r 1 50 101 tcp 40 ------- 51 50.0 153.0 0 50
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 51 50.0 153.0 0 50
r 1 51 101 tcp 40 ------- 52 51.0 154.0 0 51
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 52 51.0 154.0 0 51
r 1 52 101 tcp 40 ------- 53 52.0 155.0 0 52
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 53 52.0 155.0 0 52
r 1 53 101 tcp 40 ------- 54 53.0 156.0 0 53
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 54 53.0 156.0 0 53
r 1 54 101 tcp 40 ------- 55 54.0 157.0 0 54
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 55 54.0 157.0 0 54
r 1 55 101 tcp 40 ------- 56 55.0 158.0 0 55
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 56 55.0 158.0 0 55
r 1 56 101 tcp 40 ------- 57 56.0 159.0 0 56
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 57 56.0 159.0 0 56
r 1 57 101 tcp 40 ------- 58 57.0 160.0 0 57
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 58 57.0 160.0 0 57
r 1 58 101 tcp 40 ------- 59 58.0 161.0 0 58
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 59 58.0 161.0 0 58
r 1 59 101 tcp 40 ------- 60 59.0 162.0 0 59
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 60 59.0 162.0 0 59
r 1 60 101 tcp 40 ------- 61 60.0 163.0 0 60
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 61 60.0 163.0 0 60
r 1 61 101 tcp 40 ------- 62 61.0 164.0 0 61
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 62 61.0 164.0 0 61
r 1 62 101 tcp 40 ------- 63 62.0 165.0 0 62
+ 1 101 102 tcp 40 ------- 63 62.0 165.0 0 62
r 1 63 101 tcp 40 ------- 64 63.0 166.0 0 63
```

Comment: Provide an example of your input file.

Comment: kindly have a look, please.

Comment: [edit] your question to try again with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Right now you have a huge input file that I doubt if anyone's going to wade through to try to understand plus a tiny output file that it's not clear is even related to that input, and no explanation of the mapping from input to output except you want `to collect throughput of flows from 1 to 200`, whatever that means. The more effort you put into asking a god question (see [ask]) the less time we'll have to invest in trying to understand it and so the more people will be willing to try to help you.